# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокеты, байты

Не работает код, ошибка

```
File "chat.py", line 43, in sendproc
    sock.sendto (name.get()+':'+text.get(),('localhost',11719))
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

вот код

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 

import socket
from tkinter import *

tk=Tk()

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
s.bind(('localhost',11719))

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST,1)

text=StringVar()
name=StringVar()
name.set('HabrUser')
text.set('')
tk.title('MegaChat')
tk.geometry('400x300')

log = Text(tk)
nick = Entry(tk, textvariable=name)
msg = Entry(tk, textvariable=text)
msg.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
nick.pack(side='bottom', fill='x', expand='true')
log.pack(side='top', fill='both',expand='true')

def loopproc():
    log.see(END)
    s.setblocking(False)
    try:
        message = s.recv(128).decode()
        log.insert(END,message+'\n')
    except:
        tk.after(1,loopproc)
        return
    tk.after(1,loopproc)
    return

def sendproc(event):
    sock.sendto (name.get()+':'+text.get(),('localhost',11719))
    text.set('')

msg.bind('<Return>',sendproc)

msg.focus_set()

tk.after(1,loopproc)
tk.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 7):

Вот строка, на которую указывает ошибка:

```
sock.sendto (name.get()+':'+text.get(),('localhost',11719))
```

В тексте ошибки сказано:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Что означает примерно следующее:

> Ошибка типизации: требуется байтовый объект, а не строка

Смотрим документацию по методу `sendto`: [socket.sendto](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/socket.html#socket.socket.sendto)

Видим, что при двух предлагаемых вариантах вызова первым аргументом идут байты (а не строка):

```
socket.sendto(bytes, address)
socket.sendto(bytes, flags, address)
```

Отсюда делаем вывод, что перед отправкой нужно ваш первый аргумент перевести в байты:

```
sock.sendto((name.get()+':'+text.get()).encode(), ('localhost',11719))
```

Если строка может содержать не только ascii символы, но и например кириллицу, нужно как-то понять, в какую кодировку текст нужно кодировать (в целом, это зависит от того, какие кодировки понимает серверная сторона). Для примера, кодируем строку в кодировку utf-8:

```
sock.sendto((name.get()+':'+text.get()).encode('utf-8'), ('localhost',11719))
```

На серверной стороне пришедшие байты должны декодироваться из utf-8 в строку, грубо говоря, так: `s = received_bytes.decode('utf-8')`